# uiswitch button in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch

I'm looking an example of implementation of `UISwitch` but without using UIView, I'd like to use it for toggle on/off sound or music in my game.
Already found something but not what I want. e.g. [Creating a button using CCMenuItemToggle in cocos2d](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=458452523331) or [this example](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18748)

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a UISwitch to your header file of whatever layer your using,

opionsLayer.h

```
UISwitch *muteSwitch;
```

then implement it in your init method in the .m of your layer

```
 muteSwitch = [[ UISwitch alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100, 50, 0, 0) ];
 muteSwitch.on = YES;
[muteSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(soundOnOrOff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:muteSwitch];
[muteSwitch release];
```

then add the callback function in the .m but not in the init method,

```
- (void)soundOnOrOff:(id)sender
{

    if ([[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] mute]) {
        // This will unmute the sound
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:0];
    }
    else {
        //This will mute the sound
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:1];
    }

}
```

assuming you are using simple audio engine here though..
so you would have to import `SimpleAudioEngine` in the header too.

Comment: It works with Apple standard UISwitch control but I'm trying to use [a custom UISwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/). By the way the only think needed is to rotate the control. Thanks!